# Can't send POST request and get response correctly using NET::HTTP or httpclient?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, httprequest

I need to send different request with headers and body to PayPal. I want to use standatd class NET::HTTP, so here is my code(**ISN'T WORKING**):

```
    require "net/http"
    require "uri"
    header = {...}
    body = {...}
    url = "https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptiveAccounts/GetVerifiedStatus"
    uri = URI.parse(url)
    args = { 'header' => header,'body' => body }
    res = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, args)
    puts res.status
```

Gives me error:

```
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:141:in `read_nonblock': An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. (Errno::ECONNRESET)
```

**EDIT**
Second variant:

```
      require 'httpclient'
      require 'xmlsimple'
      header =  {"X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID" => "tok261_biz_api.abc.com",
           "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD" => "1244612379",
           "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE" => "lkfg9groingghb4uw5",
           "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT" => "NV",
           "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT" => "XML",
           "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID" =>  "APP-80W284485P519543T"
            }
      #data to be sent in the request
      data = {"emailAddress" => "denmed_1342605975_biz@gmail.com",
       "firstName"=> "Den",
       "lastName" => "Med",
       "matchCriteria"=> "NAME",
       "requestEnvelope.errorLanguage" => "en_US"}
      #initialize the request
      clnt = HTTPClient.new
      #API end point(sandbox)
      uri = "https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptiveAccounts/GetVerifiedStatus"
     #make the post
     res = clnt.post(uri, data, header)
     if res.status == 200
      @xml = XmlSimple.xml_in(res.content)
     if @xml['accountType']!=nil
    account_type = @xml['accountType'][0]
    #its pretty obvious from here init?
   if account_type.to_s() == "Business"
    puts "Business account!"
    elseif account_type.to_s() == "Premier"
    puts  "Premier Account!"
  end
   elseif account_type.to_s() == "Personal"
    puts "Personal account!"
   else
    puts "Account type not null but not a valid PayPal account type."
   end
   else
    puts "Gee! sorry! something went seriously wrong"
   end
```

This method - constantly gives me - Account type not null but not a valid PayPal account type.
But it is verified in Sandbox ! Tried to leave blank field, but it gave me the same !

Thanks for help in advance !

Comment: Where exactly is this failing? Are you having problems sending the request or is the response failing?

Comment: I will edit question and post two variants of my code: first using standard ruby class, second - using http clien gem.Wait a moment please. I need help very much!

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with your second code example, however I have used the first before (Net::HTTP) and I find it works quite well. I have generally only used it for GET, but I will try to advise on POST :)

First Thing: Headers should not be set as data to be sent with the request (which it appears you are doing) - instead, each header should be set as an attribute of the request:

```
request['X-HEADER_NAME'] = header_value
```

Here is how I suggest your code block should look if using Net::HTTP:

```
require "net/http"
require "uri"

url = "https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptiveAccounts/GetVerifiedStatus"
uri = URI.parse(url)

req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url)
req["X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID"] = "tok261_biz_api.abc.com"
req["X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD"] = "1244612379"
req["...."] = "...."   .... etc for all headers

req.set_form_data( {"emailAddress" => "denmed_1342605975_biz@gmail.com",
   "firstName"=> "Den",
   "lastName" => "Med",
   "matchCriteria"=> "NAME",
   "requestEnvelope.errorLanguage" => "en_US"} )

Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port) do |http|
    response = http.request(req)
    return response
end
```

I suggest giving something like that a try, and if it doesn't work, can you give me the exact wording of the given error?

**Note**
Another suggestion is that, whenever my application receives `Errno::ECONNRESET`, it means that the back end server is not reachable (in this case I guess that would be the paypal server) - Are you positive the server is running? And are you positive there are no firewalls or anything in place which are preventing you from connecting?